# C++ semaphore (read/write)

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore, vxworks

I had a question about reader/writer threads and I didn't want to over-complicate things so I came here for some advice.

I have an array that will ultimately be read by 4 threads and written to by 3. (1 reader 3 read/write). My goal was to somehow not have any read operation block another thread while having any write operation block all threads until finished. I'm pretty sure I know how to do this with one semaphore per thread but is there any way to accomplish this with just one binary, counting, or mutex semaphore (or something less than 1 semaphore per thread). I will be using the VxWorks semaphore library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless VxWorks supports some kind of [shared/rwlock like the POSIX one](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_init), I am afraid it is going to be a bit more complicated than just simple.

I would suggest using POSIX `pthread_rwlock_t`, if you have it. If you don't and VxWorks does not offer any equivalent alternative, you will have to build one using other primitives. It is possible to build a rwlock on top of 2 semaphores and 3 mutexes and two integer variables. See *[Concurrent Control with "Readers" and "Writers"; P.J. Courtois, F. Heymans, and D.L. Parnas; MBLE Research Laboratory; Brussels, Belgium](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362759.362813)*.

Comment: This is actually what was looking for unfortunately this is only supported by vxWorks 6.6 and beyond, otherwise like others suggested it seems to be the “Readers and Writers” problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one reader it is exactly equivalent to mutual exclusion problem (only one thread can be in). Directly using single binary semaphore should be enough. Init with one, P on entering, V on leaving.

Comment: The read/write threads are only writing in a specfic senario, so the'll be reading much more often then writing. I was hoping the 4 threads wouldn't block each other when reading.

Comment: @SirRoot In such a case you can try to implement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem . But it's likely that it won't be any faster than with readers blocking each other.